# Unable to import play.api.db.databases

Tags: scala, playframework

I am developing an application in Scala Play 2.5.4. I want to test my database interactions, and am attempting to do so by the method recommended in [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases).

The trouble is, I am unable to import the object play.api.db.Databases. I suspect that I may need to add something to my build.sbt file, but since this is part of the Play API, I'm not so sure that this is the case.

There are some things available, but not what is shown in the API doc

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to add in your `build.sbt` file this:

```
libraryDependencies += jdbc
```

After that, reload activator and update your dependencies (`activator update/sbt update`).

Note that after this you will need also to add the jdbc driver of the database you intend to use. See more info in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase

#### Edit

As stated in the comments, this may cause problems with Slick.
Unfortunately the classes you need to use are provided by that module, so if this causes you problems, you can try two things:

- Extract the class/methods you need and put them in your project: you can get the `Databases` class code in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/Databases.scala
- Try to disable the DBModule. I'm not quite sure about the syntax, so try each one of those:

  ```
  play.modules.enabled -= "play.api.db.DBModule" 
  play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this worked. I should have said in my original post that I am using the Slick API. [This FAQ](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlickFAQ) indicates that the jdbc plugin should not be enabled if you are using Slick for DB access. I hope that this won't manifest itself as some other problem. Again, thanks for your response =)

Comment: The second solution works. To disable the conflicting module, the line is `play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"` in application.conf. The Databases object code does not help much because it misses other dependences (ConnectionPool, HikariCPConnectionPool, etc., no idea where they come from).

Answer (score 0):

For people who do not have dependency to `Slick` but have the same problem. If you have added dependencies to `jdbc` and your DB driver (for example Postgresql) and problem still exists, reindexing of all dependencies via `sbt` is required. In my case closing IntelliJ Idea and subsequent reopening project back causes dependencies reindexing and problem was gone.